Updating a JUnit test in VSCode requires a full F1 for the update to register
I've got a suite of JUnit tests in a VSCode project in which if I update or add anything, the update doesn't register unless I do a full F1 clean of the project.
For example, if I add a new test I get the following:
java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching [{ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=

and it stays like that until I do a full F1.
I thought I could fix it by adding this to the settings.json file, but that didn't change anything:
{
    "java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "automatic",
    "java.debug.settings.forceBuildBeforeLaunch": true
}

Any suggestions?  Thanks.
